# Creating a toolbar for a panel with tabs

Tags: extjs, tabs, panel, toolbar

I have the working code here:

```
         var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            activeTab: 1, //sets active tab (2nd)
            title: 'Specific Data',
            floating: true, // make this panel an absolutely-positioned floating component
            items: [{
                title: 'Tab 1',
                html: 'data data data'
            }, {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'different data'
            }]

        });
```

I'm trying to add a toolbar (or buttons, not sure which I should use) to add a simple 'close window' command. Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to add a toolbar to?  You have three things here: a parent tabpanel and two tabs.

Comment: I just want to be able to close it out

Comment: It's still not really clear what "it" is here.  I added an answer that shows how you can create close buttons in both the panel and the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of adding a close button to the panel header.  You can use the `tools` config property.  The [Ext docs for this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-tools) explain the many options.

There's also a fiddle saved here: http://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/JVMUG/1/

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    activeTab: 1, //sets active tab (2nd)
    title: 'Specific Data',
    floating: true, // make this panel an absolutely-positioned floating component
    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html: 'data data data',

        // to enable closing of a tab
        closable: true

    }, {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: 'different data'
    }],

    tools: [
        { type: 'close', handler: function () { this.up('panel').close() } }
    ]


});
```

Comment: But how to actually close the panel instead of an alert?

Comment: I just changed the handler to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the docs at all?  This is very common functionality that you should be able to find very easily in Sencha's API docs.  See here for this particular issue: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tbar

Comment: @user2291971 What I am trying to say is that you have asked a couple of questions now that are very elementary if you wish to use this framework at all.  With that in mind, you do yourself a disservice if you just ask for quick answers here without looking at the documentation and trying to figure out these basic concepts on your own.  Best of luck to you.